# dotenv import in python3.7 (MacOS)

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

dotenv installed, to be sure I check this by calling pip3 and pip3.7, despite that it's same

```
(env) slonocomp:-wrapper oleg$ pip3.7 freeze | grep dotenv
django-dotenv==1.4.2
python-dotenv==0.11.0
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$ pip3 freeze | grep dotenv
django-dotenv==1.4.2
python-dotenv==0.11.0
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$
```

version of p3 and p3.7 actualy the same

```
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.4
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.4
```

But when I try to import dotenv in interactive mode (for demonstration) I got differences

```
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct 12 2019, 18:55:45)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dotenv
>>>
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct 12 2019, 18:55:45)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dotenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
>>>
(env) slonocomp:wrapper oleg$
```

The question is Why? And how to avoid this error.

Comment: Your tests are far from conclusive. What does `which python3` and `which python3.7` tell you are the complete paths of those commands?

Comment: Also, what does `python3 -m site` and `python3.7 -m site` tell you are the module search path configurations?

Comment: Last but not least, verify what Python version `pip` is associated with with the `-V` switch. So `pip3.7 -V` and `pip3 -V`, or avoid using the command-line script and go straight for the installed module with `python3.7 -m pip ...` instead of `pip3.7 ...`.

Comment: In addition to what @Martijn said, check `type python3 python3.7 pip3 pip3.7` to make sure Bash isn't overriding the executables.

Comment: Also helpful: share the output of [`pip debug`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_debug/) (requires pip version 19.2 or newer).

Comment: which python3 is /Users/oleg/Documents/PP/wrapper/env/bin/python3

which python3.7 is /usr/local/bin/python3.7 (out of venv, where dotenv is not installed)
Thank You